# Identifying an active cell in google sheets and running a script on selection

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am looking to use the active selected cell in a script as a range. I am making a spreadsheet that when you click on a cell it changes the cell and text color to be the same as the chosen color.

Comment: What is the chosen color?

Answer (score 0):

Using app script you can use the simple trigger **onSelectionChange(e)** which runs the script automatically when you change the selected cell. Try the code below:

```
function onSelectionChange(e) {
  const range = e.range;
  range.setFontColor('blue'); //change color of text
  range.setBackground('red'); //change color of cell
}
```

[image]

If you need it to check for some conditions you can also add some conditions to it. Example:

```
function onSelectionChange(e) {
  // Set background to red if a single empty cell is selected.
  const range = e.range;
  if (range.getNumRows() === 1 &&
    range.getNumColumns() === 1 &&
    range.getCell(1, 1).getValue() === '') {
    range.setFontColor('blue'); //change color of text
    range.setBackground('red'); //change color of cell
  }
}
```

Let me know if this works or if you have any questions.

Reference:

- [onSelectionChange](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onselectionchangee)

Comment: What trigger would I use?

Comment: use onSelectionChange(e) trigger. Try the apps script code I have included in the posted answer. Let me know if this is how you want it to work.